# Google Stack column chart works fine with Chrome but doesnt work with IE8

Tags: google-visualization

I looked out for solution for my problem but couldnt find any solution.

I have a code which will work fine with Chrome and Firefox, but throws error "Expected identifier, string or number" with IE8

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
         var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
         'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
        ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
        ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, ''],
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true,
      };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me with just `<div id="chart_div"></div>`. You have also `width` and `height` options set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errant commas that could be causing that problem:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General', 'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
    ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
    ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, ''], // <-- this comma should go away
]);

var options = {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true, // <-- and this comma as well
};
```

IE will throw a temper tantrum to rival a petulant 2-year-old child when presented with a comma at the end of an array or object.